# How can i free all the items of a FreeList?

Tags: memory-management, d, allocation

`SharedFreeList` has the right method but I don't see how to free all the nodes of a `FreeList`:

```
module runnable;

import std.experimental.allocator.building_blocks;
import std.experimental.allocator.mallocator;
import std.experimental.allocator;

shared SharedFreeList!(Mallocator, 0, unbounded) heap1;
FreeList!(Mallocator, 0, unbounded) heap2;

shared static ~this()
{
    heap1.deallocateAll; // OK
}

static ~this()
{
    heap2.deallocateAll; // no prop deallocateAll for...
}
```

While this example is pointless, I may want to do the same in a class destructor. With certain static parameters, `FreeList.deallocateAll` seems to be deactivated, however there must be a way to deallocate all the nodes in the list, right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according [DOC](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_experimental_allocator_building_blocks_free_list.html#.FreeList.deallocateAll):

> Defined only if ParentAllocator defines deallocateAll. If so, forwards to it and resets the freelist.

You use `Mallocator` which does not have `deallocateAll` so you can't use it. But `SharedFreeList` has own implementation of `deallocateAll`.

So I would probably create an issue on https://issues.dlang.org. Because I belive same method could be implement for `FreeList` too.

Comment: I haven't looked at the implementation of `FreeList`, but it might only keep track of the free objects, and not any of the objects that have been allocated. In that case, it would not be possible to implement `deallocateAll`.